# OpenGl problem with indicies

Tags: opengl, android

hi guys i'm new of these topics(opengl and others)
To begin i want only to create a simple circle that can be route on touchevent. So i decided to learn opengl and to try.

These is my class called circle

```
public class Circle
{

private ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
private FloatBuffer floatBuffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
private ShortBuffer indicesbuffer;


float[] buffer=new float[360*3];

float[] color={
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,

        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
};

short indices[]=new short[180*2];


public Circle()
{

    for(int i=0;i<360;i++)
    {
        buffer[i]=(float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians((double)i))*0.5f;
        buffer[++i]=(float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians((double)i))*0.5f;
        buffer[++i]=0f;
       // Log.i("",""+buffer[i-2]+" "+buffer[i-1]+" "+buffer[i]);
    }
    short count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<360;i++)
    {
        indices[i++]=count;
        indices[i]=(short)(360-count);
        count++;
        Log.i("Prova",""+indices[i-1]+" "+indices[i]);
    }
    byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*buffer.length);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    floatBuffer= byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    floatBuffer.put(buffer);
    floatBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*color.length);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    colorBuffer= byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(color);
    colorBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length*4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    indicesbuffer=byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
    indicesbuffer.put(indices);
    indicesbuffer.position(0);

}

public void draw(GL10 gl10)
{
    gl10.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl10.glLoadIdentity();

    gl10.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,floatBuffer);
    gl10.glColorPointer(4,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,colorBuffer);


    gl10.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl10.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl10.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES,360
            ,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indicesbuffer);

    gl10.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl10.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}

public void route(float x,float y,GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glClearColor(255,255,255,0);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glRotatef(x,0,1,0);
    gl.glRotatef(y,-1,0,0);

    this.draw(gl);
}
}
```

it was really simply..i use goniometric function to get polar coordinates of circle and then i draw it. I want to draw it red colored. So i use indicies to unite the points that are opposite respect x axis. But the output is this[image]

These is the main and render code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer,View.OnTouchListener{

int wi,he;
    Circle cube= new Circle();



    float la_x,la_y,diff_x,diff_y=0;
    GLSurfaceView gl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gl= new GLSurfaceView(this);
        final Prova prova= new Prova(100,100);
        gl.setRenderer(this);
        this.addContentView(gl,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        gl.setOnTouchListener(this);
        gl.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    }



    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        gl.glClearColor(255,255,255,0);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);





        cube.draw(gl);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

            cube.route(diff_x, diff_y,gl);
            Log.i("Differencese",""+diff_x+" "+diff_y);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x=event.getX();
        float y= event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                la_x=x;
                la_y=y;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                diff_x=x-la_x;
                diff_y= y-la_y;

                la_x=x;
                la_y=y;
                gl.requestRender();
                break;

            case  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                la_x=0;
                la_y=0;
                break;

        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Can anyone plese tell where is my errors.. Sorry for the english and thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to draw 179 vertical lines.
You want to skip point 0, since you didn't define a point 360, and if you had, it would have had the same location as point 0.

```
short indices[]=new short[179*2];

count = 1;
for(int i=0;i<358;i++)
{
    indices[i++]=count;
    indices[i]=(short)(360-count);
    count++;
    Log.i("Prova",""+indices[i-1]+" "+indices[i]);
}
```

As for color, you've only assigned the color for the first 8 points.

For those 8 lines, the color will start out red, then vary towards black.